# Hide parts of mesh in weight paint mode? (v2.90)

Tags: weight-painting

I'm rigging a fancy coat, and part of the shoulder mesh is hidden by a giant lapel. I hid it for Edit mode (selected the mesh to be hidden and hit <kbd>H</kbd>), but that didn't seem to hide it in Weight Paint mode also. A 4-yr-old answer on Reddit says I can use face or vertex masking to hide this part of the mesh; where did it go in v2.90, or how can I hide parts of a mesh while still being able to weight-paint freely across the visible mesh? Thanks!

EDIT: The tooltip for the little box and "point on box" icons in the upper left say those are face and vertex mask selection for painting. That will indeed hide the lapel (which is roughly the height of the distance between the shoulder and pelvis bones), but it doesn't seem like I'm able to edit beyond a specified range, which doesn't entirely help.

[image]

Comment: If you don't find it a workaround could be completely separating the parts of the mesh you wish to hide by selecting it in edit mode and pressing p. Then hiding it in object mode.

Comment: I could certainly do that. I didn't earlier because of an inexplicably messy UV map (I mapped it correctly, so why did the UVs go all wonky as if I'd re-pinned them??), but I think the parts I care about are still nicely UV'ed and thus separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was no selecting enough (e.g. everything else) vertices to have editable in Weight Paint mode. After hiding the desired mesh, selecting everything still visible with <kbd>A</kbd> make all vertices paintable.

Comment: so already solved? have any other questions about?

Comment: Yes, though I can't accept my own answer yet. I do have another question (might deserve its own post though?) That coat I'm working on has two front coattails on their own mesh because I need them separate for a transparency shapekey. Is it possible to view/edit two meshes at once in Weight Paint mode (e.g. eyedrop from the correct one to the incorrect one)?

Comment: transparency shapekey? two in weigh that I know n is possible, but you can use modifier data transfer, to copy

Answer (score 1):

in edit mode select faces and press h, in weight mode and active vertex selection and press A [image]

better: Active paint mask leftside vertex selection and select faces and paint

Comment: I'd found that, but my mistake was selecting only a few vertices in Edit mode; these were the "limited vertices" I saw in Weight mode. Thanks!